# Rename a collection via Doctrine MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine

been searching for an answer to this and found nothing so here is a little brain teaser for you.

How can I rename a collection using Doctrine? The docs give no support for renaming a collection or even cloning it but this is fairly straight forward functionality(to me anyway) and thought that there may very well be a good reason for not including it.

Cheers for any response,
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions with the Mongo PECL maintainers this functionality has not reached the pecl level yet. However there is still a silver lining.

Doctrine\MongoDb\Database has a command() method which allows you to do something similar to:

```
$mdb = ''; // Really it would be a mongo adapter
$db = new \Doctrine\MongoDB\Database(
    $mdb, // Our \Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection
    $mdb->selectDatabase('admin')->getMongoDB(),
    new \Doctrine\Common\EventManager()
);

$success = $db->command(array('renameCollection' => 'foo', 'to' => 'bar'));
```